# Error when model has dynamic property ASP .NET Core 6

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, dynamic, model

I am using ASP .NET Core 6 and MongoDB.Driver 2.21.0 I need a model that has a dynamic or generic property.

The property in question is declared as follows:

```
public dynamic data { get; set; }
```

After creating, the services and the controller, when I try to create using swagger in mongoDB I get this error:

> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: An error occurred while serializing the data property of class prueba.Models.Servicio.Servicio: Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.
>
> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.
>
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.SerializeDiscriminatedValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value, Type actualType)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, Object value)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeMember(BsonSerializationContext context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)

I have been investigating and I have not found any solution, could you tell me how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

I have try to change the objectSerializer but I don't know if I'm doing it well.

Comment: There is no dymic table proprety inside the mongodb so the driver will not know how to map the data with it.One possible way is creating a custom model mapper to mapping it. Details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082437/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-serialize-dynamic-field-on-model).